# What are the exact differences between stereocilia and microvilli?

Tags: histology

This is a question in an old exam of Histology. I tried to answer the question, and I've made many searching attempts, but without resulting in any fixed/exact information. In some [articles](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stereocilia) on the web, I've read the stereocilia and microvilli have both actin core, and this [website](http://www.dematice.org/ressources/PCEM1/Histologie/P1_histo_006/Web/co/Module_DIFFERENCIATIONS_MEMBRANE_PLASMIQUE_7.html) states that stereocilia doesn't have actin filaments! I'm just feeling lost at this point. And now, I'm just searching for an exact answer for that question.

Note : It may be a super easy question for you. So please note that I'm a novice self-learner at Histology.

Comment: Both are actin based.

Comment: Is this information come from a trusted resource ?

Comment: Haha well I don't know… do you trust me?

Comment: http://www.uniprot.org/locations/SL-0293 and http://www.uniprot.org/locations/SL-0302

Comment: Thanks. But I still need to know the differences between them.

Answer (score 1):

**Stereocilia are basically modified microvilli**. They are much longer than microvilli, and lack the villin protein.

According to Ross histology textbook, they both contain actin filaments.

Answer (score 0):

Microvilli are found in locations where their function is related to absorption and secretion, for example, in the intestine. Stereocilia have more or less the same function but are rare. Although both have an actin core, there are significant cytoskeletal differences in stereocilia. These include the presence of fimbrin and the absence of villin, and so on.

#### References:

1. https://www.researchgate.net/publication/318305308_Difference_Between_Cilia_and_Microvilli
2. https://www.biologydiscussion.com/difference/difference-among-cilia-stereo-cilia-and-microvilli-animal-tissue
3. https://pubmed.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/8731041/